# How do I enter '·' (middle dot) in agda-mode?

Tags: emacs, agda, agda-mode

I'm working through a [paper](https://nicolaspouillard.fr/publis/jfp-unified-binders.pdf) that uses the middle-dot character in Agda code. I'd like to be able to type it up without copy/paste. How can I enter it with agda-mode?

I've tried typical resources such as

- http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/emacs-mode.html
- http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Docs.UnicodeInput

Comment: Yet another useful collection: http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Symbols.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\cdot` gives you `·` and `\.` gives you `∙` (these are different symbols).

If you can copy/paste a character, then you can discover how to type it by choosing the "Agda/Information about the character at point" option in menu (or using `M-x describe-char`) and looking at the `to input:` section.

Comment: Thanks `\cdot` was the one I was after. "Character at point" is excellent!

Comment: `C-u C-x =` also displays the information about the character currently under the cursor.